# Why does a Nodeport need a "port" in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

[image]

The nodeport takes in 3 parameters in the service yaml.

- port
- targetPort
- nodePort

Since all you wanted was to map a port on the node(nodeport) to the port on the container(targetPort), why do we need to provide the port of the service?

Is this because Nodeport is internally implemented **on top of** ClusterIP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nodeport is internally implemented on top of ClusterIP" - correct.

The port in the Kubernetes Service definition is used to specify the port on which the service will listen for traffic within the Kubernetes cluster. This is the port that will be exposed to other pods in the cluster as an endpoint for the service. When a request is made to this port by a client within the cluster, the traffic will be routed to one of the pods selected by the Service based on its load balancing algorithm.

The nodePort is used to expose the service on a port on the node itself, which allows the service to be accessed from outside the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

`TargetPort` is the actual port on which your application is running inside the container & the port number that the Service should forward traffic to.

The `Port` is the port number that the Service will listen on internally and can be used when one pod or application within the cluster wants to access the service.

As defined over [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#multi-port-services), for some Services, you need to expose more than one port. So in the example defined in that link:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 9377
```

The service definition exposes two ports: `http` and `https`. The `http` port listens on port 80 and forwards traffic to port `9376` on the `pod`, while the `https` port listens on port `443` and forwards traffic to port `9377` on the `pod`.

So that's how `port` can be used different to `targetPort`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Makes sense. Btw, the definition you specified is for ClusterIP service correct? If I wanted Nodeport, would I be specifying two nodeports, one for http and one for https?

Comment: Yes, that's correct